# Is there a way to export Xcode key bindings?

Tags: xcode

I have a mac at work and want to sync my key bindings at home to it.  I don't see an export button in the Preferences menu.  Is there some other way to export my custom key bindings?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From Xcode 5 to Xcode 15 the correct folder you should backup is ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData where you'll find the following items:

- /Code Snippets
  Your user generated code snippets: [NSHipster on XCode Snippets](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/)
- /FontsAndColorThemes
  Any default themes you've modified: [XCode 5 Themes](http://michaelmangold.com/xcode-themes/)
- /KeyBindings
  Default.keybindings which you can open with xcode (xml/plist): [keybindins in xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056518/key-bindings-in-xcode-5)
- IDEDocumentationWindow.xcuserstate
- IDEOrganizerWindowController.xcuserstate
- IDEPreferencesController.xcuserstate
  3 Files that maintain the state for the documentation, organizer and preferences windows.

Comment: warning: it seems this file is one way. ie, if you edit it manually, then open xcode, and do anything in keybindings prefs interface, it will be overwritten.

Comment: Making an alias - wouldn't that work? It reads the alias file fine, but haven't tried loading it at home yet.

Answer (score 18):

In XCode 4.0.2 the key bindings are found in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/

In Xcode 4.3.x and 5.0 the key bindings are in the same place.

Answer (score 12):

IN Xcode 8.x.x the keys bindings are still here

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/`

Answer (score 2):

You'll find files in ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Key Bindings.  I imagine you can just copy one of these files and put it in the corresponding place on another machine.

Comment: This answer is now dated.  See the answer by @TPoschel for the location used for XCode 4.0.2