# Key bindings in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, xcode5

I used to do this:
[Xcode duplicate line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266170/xcode-4-duplicate-line)

But IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist doesn't exist anymore.

There is a folder called "KeyBindings" with a blank text file in it.

So how do we set up key bindings now?

Specifically I just want command-D to duplicate the line the cursor is in, which is a basic functionality of every other IDE except Xcode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `KeyBindings` directory stores just per-user key bindings for *already available operations* in Xcode. On the other hand, the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` lets you *add an operation* to Xcode itself (and afterwards put a key binding into your `KeyBindings` dir).

Just **put the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` file again into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources`** (the location is the same as in Xcode 4). And make yourself a backup, since each Xcode upgrade will default your customized bindings (if there's a better solution for Xcode upgrades, I'm all ears).